# Trigger multiple triggers at once

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, cascade

I am working on optimizing a delete query and I saw that when I delete multiple rows, the triggers run 1 per row. For example for 100 rows I get:

```
Trigger for constraint other_table_1_fid_fkey: time=3.644 calls=100
```

Is it possible to make it more efficient?

Comment: Use a statement trigger instead of a row trigger

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FrankHeikens. Can you please elaborate more?